# Show window from NIB preventing multiple instances

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

I am trying to load and show window from nib and don't understand how to do that correctly.
Now I use the following code:

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    
    var statusItem: NSStatusItem!
    var statusButton: NSStatusBarButton!
    
    var menu: NSMenu!
    var menuItemTitle: NSMenuItem!
    var menuItemInfo: NSMenuItem!
    var menuItemQuit: NSMenuItem!
    
    var menuImage: NSImage!
    
    var titleView: TitleView!
        
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        menuImage = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "menubar.rectangle", accessibilityDescription: "Image")
        
        statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.squareLength)
        statusButton = statusItem.button
        statusButton.image = menuImage
        
        menuItemTitle = NSMenuItem(title: "First", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
        menuItemInfo = NSMenuItem(title: "Info", action: #selector(actionInfo), keyEquivalent: "i")
        menuItemQuit = NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: #selector(actionQuit), keyEquivalent: "q")
        
        menu = NSMenu()
        menu.addItem(menuItemTitle)
        menu.addItem(menuItemInfo)
        menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())
        menu.addItem(menuItemQuit)
        
        statusItem.menu = menu
        
        titleView = TitleView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 70))
        menuItemTitle.view = titleView
    }
    
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    }
    
    func applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState(_ app: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    @objc func actionQuit() {
        NSApplication.shared.terminate(self)
    }
    
    var infoWindowController: InfoWindowController!
    @objc func actionInfo() {
        infoWindowController = InfoWindowController()
        infoWindowController.showWindow(self)
//        infoWindowController.showWin(self)
    }
    
}
```

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

class InfoWindowController: NSWindowController {
    
    @IBOutlet var infoWindow: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var infoIcon: NSImageView!
    
    override var windowNibName: String! {
        return "InfoWindow"
    }
    
    override func windowDidLoad() {
        print("windowDidLoad")
    }
        
    func showWin(_ sender: Any) {
        _ = window
        showWindow(sender)
        /// This does not work
//        window?.center()
//        window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        
        //This works with the first NSViewController.window access
//        infoWindow?.center()
//        infoWindow?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
    }
}
```

InfoWindow.xib

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.Cocoa.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="21701" targetRuntime="MacOSX.Cocoa" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" customObjectInstantitationMethod="direct">
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="macosx"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.CocoaPlugin" version="21701"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <customObject id="-2" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="InfoWindowController" customModule="GUI" customModuleProvider="target">
            <connections>
                <outlet property="infoWindow" destination="QvC-M9-y7g" id="jBK-DN-ufD"/>
            </connections>
        </customObject>
        <customObject id="-1" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="FirstResponder"/>
        <customObject id="-3" userLabel="Application" customClass="NSObject"/>
        <window title="Window" allowsToolTipsWhenApplicationIsInactive="NO" autorecalculatesKeyViewLoop="NO" releasedWhenClosed="NO" visibleAtLaunch="NO" animationBehavior="default" id="QvC-M9-y7g">
            <windowStyleMask key="styleMask" titled="YES" closable="YES" miniaturizable="YES" resizable="YES"/>
            <windowPositionMask key="initialPositionMask" leftStrut="YES" rightStrut="YES" topStrut="YES" bottomStrut="YES"/>
            <rect key="contentRect" x="196" y="240" width="480" height="270"/>
            <rect key="screenRect" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="2560" height="1415"/>
            <view key="contentView" wantsLayer="YES" id="EiT-Mj-1SZ">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="480" height="270"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                <subviews>
                    <textField horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="750" fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="2Ad-gr-Tqg">
                        <rect key="frame" x="185" y="166" width="56" height="16"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMinY="YES"/>
                        <textFieldCell key="cell" lineBreakMode="clipping" title="Hi there!" id="lZn-he-q8e">
                            <font key="font" usesAppearanceFont="YES"/>
                            <color key="textColor" name="labelColor" catalog="System" colorSpace="catalog"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" name="textBackgroundColor" catalog="System" colorSpace="catalog"/>
                        </textFieldCell>
                    </textField>
                </subviews>
            </view>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="105" y="144"/>
        </window>
    </objects>
</document>
```

I have no storyboard, so I use main.swift:

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

let app = NSApplication.shared
let delegate = AppDelegate()
app.delegate = delegate

_ = NSApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
```

According to the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowcontroller/1535137-loadwindow), I need to "access the window property so the windowDidLoad() and windowWillLoad() methods are invoked". And I observe windowDidLoad exactly after execution of the `_ = window` line. But even after, my controler's ``window` property is still nil. But IBOutlet begins to work, so my working code looks like this:

```
    func show() {
        _ = window
        infoWindow?.center()
        infoWindow?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
    }
```

My question: is it possible to load and show window from xib without IBOutlet? Or just with IBOutlet, without accessing NSWindowController's window property? How to do it in the "right" way? And also, how could I prevent user to activate this window more than once?
Thank you!

Update: Dear colleagues, thank you for your help! I appreciate it so much. I've [made a github repo](https://github.com/BbIKTOP/NibWindowMVE) to make it easier to track changes you suggest me to try.

Comment: Post a [mre] please. What's in the xib and how is `InfoWindowController` instantiated?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking multiple different questions, which makes things very confusing. From the title of your question it seems that you are getting multiple info windows being shown (presumably one extra one each time you select the Info menu item). I think this is because your `actionInfo` handler is creating a new instance each time it is called. The original code will be overwriting the `infoWindowController` property with a new instance.

You could create your Info window once and use `lazy` to delay the creation until it is needed:

```
lazy private var infoWindowController: InfoWindowController = {
        InfoWindowController()
}()
@objc func actionInfo() {
    infoWindowController.showWindow(self)
}
```

Note that this will keep the instance of the info window controller alive even if you close the window.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to confuse. I've been asked to add details, so I did copy-paste more of my code. Really, I have 2 problems with it. First, I am able to make this nib-window visible using both outlet and NSWindowController.window. So, the first part of my question was "is it possible to use just one - either outlet or NSWindowController.window property?" I'd prefer not to use outlet, but any approach will be ok. The second part is that I want to show this window only once. I mean, I managed to show it using outlet and |window" property, and I'd like to make it shown just once

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to you window controller.

```
override init(window: NSWindow!)
{
    super.init(window: window)
}

required init(coder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: coder)!
}

convenience init()
{
    self.init(windowNibName: "InfoWindowController", owner:(Any).self)
    
}
```

Then create the window with;

```
   var myWindow = InfoWindowController(windowNibName: "InfoWindowController")
   myWindow.showWindow(self)
```

Comment: Does not work. Probably I've missed something. I've made an mve and updated my quesion. You could see different approaches I tried, commented out in the code

Comment: You left out the parameters in  infoWindowController = InfoWindowController(). Should be infoWindowController = InfoWindowController(windowNibName: "InfoWindowController")

Comment: `InfoWindowController` implements `windowNibName`. It should work.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Copypasted your code (except my nib name is "InfoWindow" and nothing happens. Still no window. Got a message: "2023-04-12 16:25:09.126585+0300 GUI[87215:1671845] [default] CGSWindowShmemCreateWithPort failed on port 0", dunno, maybe it's related

Comment: Does the nib file have a window object? And is the nib File's Owner set to InfoWindowController?

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to load and show window from xib without the infoWindow IBOutlet?

Yes. `InfoWindowController` has an outlet property `infoWindow`. The superclass of `InfoWindowController`, `NSWindowController` has a property `window`. In the xib, the `infoWindow` outlet is connected to the window but the `window` outlet isn't.

Solution: Connect the `window` outlet in the xib to the window.

Steps:

1. Select InfoWindow.xib
2. Select the File's Owner
3. Go to the Connections Inspector
4. Drag from the window outlet to the window

[image: xib in IB]

You don't have to call `_ = window`. Methods `windowDidLoad()` and `windowWillLoad()` will be called automatically when the window is loaded, for example by `showWindow`.

Comment: I also thought so but in this case window does not appear. As I wrote, I see "windowDidLoad" called but nothing happens when I call showWindow

Comment: @BbIKTOP Is `self.window` pointing to a window in `windowDidLoad`?

Comment: As I wrote: "But even after, my controler's ``window` property is still nil" in any case. Probably I am doing something wrong, just cannot realize what exactly.

Comment: added `print("windowDidLoad/ window \(window == nil ? "nil" : "not nil" )")` to the windowDidLoad and observe "windowDidLoad/ window nil"

Comment: @BbIKTOP Did you connect the window outlet of the File's Owner (InfoWindowController) in the xib to the window?

Comment: sure, the nib is in the question

Comment: sorry, wrong xib. Updated with the current one

Comment: @BbIKTOP The `window` outlet is not connected in your xib.

Comment: I've made changes I has been asked for. but I've updated it in the question. I'd probably rather make a github repo to share this

Comment: @BbIKTOP I added steps how to connect the window outlet.

Comment: But it is connected and currently the only way i am able to use to show window is via outlet

Comment: Could you just download my mve and try?

Comment: I did try your project, the window outlet was not connected. After connecting the window outlet it works. The `window` outlet is the `window` property of `NSWindowController`, not the `infoWindow` outlet of the `InfoWindowController` class.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Could you please fork and make changes?